# Can I store objects in my browsers Windows local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I am doing a lot of the following:

```
var store = window.localStorage;

var accountID = store.getItem('AccountID'),
        pageID = store.getItem('PageID'),
        referenceID = store.getItem('ReferenceID'),
        topicID = store.getItem('TopicID');
```

Is there a way I could do this more efficiently. For example could I create an object in Javascript and store / get the whole object at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you try it, you'll find that you can't. Whatever you store will be set as its `toString` value.

One possibility depending on what data you're storing would be to stringify it as JSON data, then parse it when needed.

```
var data = {foo:"bar"};

window.localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(data));

var fetched = window.localStorage.getItem("test");

var parsed = JSON.parse(fetched);

alert(parsed.foo); // "bar"
```

Of course this will limit you to the types of data that are JSON compatible.